# Is it OK to ask questions in a paper-presentation about subjects that were not covered in the presentation?

Tags: publications, presentation

I was at a presentation for a paper that I have studied and I have several doubts about some aspects of it. During that presentation, the author didn't go into details around the novel-theories proposed that I find more difficult to comprehend. I thought I could try to ask him after the talk, but he just vanished.

Would it have been OK to ask questions about these issues even though they were not addressed at all during the talk?

Comment: If asking, then I'd suggest trying to add context that connects your question with the talk. E.g., "you mentioned X and in your paper you expand upon that idea to derive Y," followed by your question. That way the other members of the audience benefit from the question and the answer. Without such context, the audience are less likely to benefit.